# Why does the difference emerge between this two codes in C: Array Implementation for Stack and Linked List Implementation for Stack?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, linked-list, stack

```
typedef int Element;

typedef struct {
    Element *stack;
    int max_size;
    int top;
} Stack;

//I added more codes..
Stack *CreateStack(int size)
{
    Stack *pStack = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if(pStack == NULL)
        return NULL;

    pStack->stack = (Element *)malloc(size * sizeof(Element));
    if(pStack->stack == NULL){
        free(pStack);
        return NULL;
    }

    pStack->max_size = size;
    pStack->top = -1;

    return pStack;

}


//this for linked list
typedef struct tStackNode{
    Element data;
    struct tStackNode *next;
} StackNode;

typedef struct {
    int count;
    StackNode *top;
} StackHead;

StackHead* CreateStack(int size)
//size is not used in linked list implmentation
{
    StackHead *pStack = (StackHead *) malloc(sizeof(StackHead));
    if(pStack == NULL)
        return NULL;
    pStack->count = 0;
    pStack->top = NULL;

    return pStack;
}
```

The first one is for the array and the second one is for the Linked List.

I added more codes for 'creating stack'.

Why would the first one uses the integer pointer value and the second one needs int value....

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the list, each node represent a *single* value, right? So it makes sense that the node only contains one `Element` value. For the stack, `stack` is a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: There is some information missing, show more code.

Comment: Because they are implemented differently?  The first one will dynamically allocate elements and hook them to the top of the stack, the second dynamically allocates nodes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. What about the array? Doesn't it need any value to contain?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks. I added more about creating stack. I can show you the whole but stackexchange blocks too-many-code question..

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Thanks. For the head, the top is the pointer pointing some node, right?

Comment: I would assume so, @AliciaMay

Answer (score 1):

In the linked list the data element is stored in each list node.

With the array implementation the data is stored in an array the the *stack pointer points to.  Using this will require a stack of the appropriate size to be allocated and assigned to the stack pointer.

Comment: Ah so does the array implementation need some other memory to place the real data?

Comment: Yes, either malloc'd or a static/global array that's available to the module.